# How to create a dropdown that contain of buttons and label

Tags: python, frameworks, kivy, dropdown

I am working in kivy (python) and I need dropdown to place here instead of textinput. but I could not do this, help me to continue work.the screenshot is following. my goal is to replace these textinputs with dropdowns.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zL8K.png)

The py file code is

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder

class CustomDropDown(DropDown): 
    pass
class delivery_managementWindow(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.dropdown = CustomDropDown() 

        self.mainbutton = Button(text ='Do you in college?', 
                                size_hint_x = 0.6, size_hint_y = 0.15) 
        self.add_widget(self.mainbutton) 
        self.mainbutton.bind(on_release = self.dropdown.open) 
        self.dropdown.bind(on_select = lambda\
            instance, x: setattr(self.mainbutton, 'text', x)) 
        self.dropdown.bind(on_select = self.callback) 

    def callback(self, instance, x): 
        print ( "The chosen mode is: {0}" . format ( x ) ) 

class delivery_managementApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return delivery_managementWindow()

if __name__ =='__main__':
    delivery_managementApp().run()
```

Now its kv file is also

```
<CustomDropDown>:
    Button: 
        text: 'College Name'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 44
        on_release: root.select('College is') 
    Label: 
        text: 'Not in college'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 44
    Button: 
        text: 'KccItm'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 44
        on_release: root.select('Kcc')

<delivery_managementWindow>:
    id:delivery_managment_main_window
    orientation:'vertical'
    padding:5
    spacing:5
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba:(.1,.30,.35,1)
        Rectangle:
            pos:self.pos
            size:self.size
    BoxLayout:
        id:header
        size_hint_x:1
        size_hint_y:None
        height:50
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba:(.06,.45,.45,1)
            Rectangle:
                pos:self.pos
                size:self.size
        Label:
            text:"Delivery Management"
            bold: True
            font_size:18
            # color:(.06,.45,.45,1)

    BoxLayout:
        id:''
        orientation:'horizontal'
        BoxLayout:
            id:add_edit_form
            orientation:'vertical'
            size_hint_y:1
            size_hint_x:1.5
            spacing:5
            padding:5
            # height:40
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    # rgba:(.02,.25,.45,1)
                Rectangle:
                    pos:self.pos
                    size:self.size
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint_y:None
                size_hint_x:1
                # padding:5
                
                height:40
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgba:(1,1,1,.8)
                    Rectangle:
                        pos:self.pos
                        size:self.size
                Label:
                    id:lbl_header
                    text:"Add New/Edit Delivery"
                    font_size:17
                    bold: True
                    color:(0,0,1,1)

            GridLayout:
                id:grd
                cols:2
                size_hint_y:1
                size_hint_x:1
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgba:(.06,.45,.45,1)
                    Rectangle:
                        pos:self.pos
                        size:self.size
                    
                Label:
                    text:"Delivery :"
                    bold: True
                    font_size:17
                BoxLayout: 
                    id:dropdown_box
                
                Label:
                    text:"Our Ref: Inv-sup :"
                    bold: True
                    font_size:17
                TextInput:
                Label:
                    text:"Invoice :"
                    bold: True
                    font_size:17
                TextInput:
                Label:
                    text:"Supplier :"
                    bold: True
                    font_size:17
                TextInput:
                Label:
                    text:"Date :"
                    bold: True
                    font_size:17
                TextInput:
                
                BoxLayout:
                    cols:2
                    CheckBox:
                    Label:
                        text:'Delivery for Store Room'
                Button:
                    id:btn_proceed
                    text:'Proceed Next'
            BoxLayout:
                id:keyboard
                size_hint_y:1
                size_hint_x:1
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgba:(0,0,1,1)   
                    Rectangle:
                        pos:self.pos
                        size:self.size
        BoxLayout:
            id:keypad_section
            orientation:'vertical'
            size_hint_y:1
            size_hint_x:.7
            # padding:5
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba:(.1,.30,.35,1)
                Rectangle:
                    pos:self.pos
                    size:self.size
            AnchorLayout:
                size_hint_x:1
                size_hint_y:.2
                anchor_x: 'center'
                anchor_y: 'center'
                
                canvas: 
                    Color: 
                        rgba:(1,1,1,.9)
                    Rectangle: 
                        pos: self.pos 
                        size: self.size 
                Button: 
                    text: 'Go To Sale'
                    size_hint_y:.7
                    size_hint_x:.5
                    font_size:17
                    bold: True
                    background_normal:''
                    background_color:(.06,.45,.45,1)
            GridLayout:
                cols:3
                id:keypad
                size_hint_y:1
                size_hint_x:1
                spacing:5
                padding:5
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgba:(.1,.30,.35,1)
                    Rectangle:
                        pos:self.pos
                        size:self.size
                Button:
                    text:'1'
                    bold: True
                    font_size:18
                    background_normal:''
                    background_color:(.06,.45,.45,1)
                Button:
                    text:'2'
                    bold: True
                    font_size:18
                    background_normal:''
                    background_color:(.06,.45,.45,1)
                Button:
                    text:'3'
                    bold: True
                    font_size:18
                    background_normal:''
                    background_color:(.06,.45,.45,1)
                Button:
                    text:'4'
                    bold: True
                    font_size:18
                    background_normal:''
                    background_color:(.06,.45,.45,1)
                Button:
                    text:'5'
                    bold: True
                    font_size:18
                    background_normal:''
                    background_color:(.06,.45,.45,1)
                Button:
                    text:'6'
                    bold: True
                    font_size:18
                    background_normal:''
                    background_color:(.06,.45,.45,1)
                Button:
                    text:'7'
                    bold: True
                    font_size:18
                    background_normal:''
                    background_color:(.06,.45,.45,1)
                Button:
                    text:'8'
                    bold: True
                    font_size:18
                    background_normal:''
                    background_color:(.06,.45,.45,1)
                Button:
                    text:'9'
                    bold: True
                    font_size:18
                    background_normal:''
                    background_color:(.06,.45,.45,1)
                Button:
                    text:'00'
                    bold: True
                    font_size:18
                    background_normal:''
                    background_color:(.06,.45,.45,1)
                Button:
                    text:'0'
                    bold: True
                    font_size:18
                    background_normal:''
                    background_color:(.06,.45,.45,1)
                Button:
                    text:'*'
                    bold: True
                    font_size:18
                    background_normal:''
                    background_color:(.06,.45,.45,1)
                Button:
                    text:'<--'
                    bold: True
                    font_size:18
                    background_normal:''
                    background_color:(.06,.45,.45,1)
                Button:
                    text:'-'
                    bold: True
                    font_size:18
                    background_normal:''
                    background_color:(.06,.45,.45,1)
                Button:
                    text:'Enter'
                    bold: True
                    font_size:18
                    background_normal:''
                    background_color:(.06,.45,.45,1)
                
            BoxLayout: 
                id:btn_section
                size_hint_y:.2
                size_hint_x:1
                spacing:5
                padding:5
                canvas.before:
                    Color:
                        rgba:(.1,.30,.35,1)
                    Rectangle:
                        pos:self.pos
                        size:self.size
                Button:
                    id:btn_exit
                    text:'Exit'
                    size_hint_x:1
                    size_hint_y:1
                    font_size:18
                    bold:True
                    color:(.8,0,0,.8)
                    background_normal:''
                    background_color:(.06,.45,.45,1)
                    size_hint_x:1
                    size_hint_y:1

                Button:
                    id:btn_finish
                    text: "Finish Delivery"
                    font_size:18
                    bold:True
                    background_normal:''
                    background_color:(.06,.45,.45,1)
                    size_hint_x:1
                    size_hint_y:1
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: oh sorry dear...now I have attached my code

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `DropDown` to replace each `TextInput`. I will provide an example of how to do that for the delivery option and you can follow that pattern for any other `DropDowns` that you want.

First, define the main button for the new `DropDown` in the `kv`:

```
            Label:
                text:"Delivery :"
                bold: True
                font_size:17
            # BoxLayout: 
            #     id:dropdown_box
            Button:
                id: del_opt_main_butt
                text: 'Select delivery option'
                on_release: root.open_delivery_options_dropdown()
```

Then make a rule for the new `DropDown` (also in the `kv`):

```
<DeliveryOptionDropDown>:
    on_select:
        app.root.ids.del_opt_main_butt.text = args[1]
        app.delivery_option_callback(*args)
    Button:
        text: 'Overnight'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 44
        on_release: root.select(self.text)
    Button:
        text: 'Two Day'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 44
        on_release: root.select(self.text)
    Button:
        text: 'Snail Mail'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 44
        on_release: root.select(self.text)
```

and define the new `DropDown` class:

```
class DeliveryOptionDropDown(DropDown):
    pass
```

Then add the method to open the new `Dropdown` to the `delivery_managementWindow` class:

```
def open_delivery_options_dropdown(self):
    self.delivery_options_dropdown = DeliveryOptionDropDown()
    self.delivery_options_dropdown.open(self.ids.del_opt_main_butt)
```

Then add a callback to the `App` class:

```
def delivery_option_callback(self, instance, selection):
    print('chosen delivery option is', selection)
```

Those last two methods are located in the `delivery_managementWindow` and the `App` classes just for simplicity (`root` and `app` are predefined variables in the `kv`).